# Hashie::Mash stored as string and unable to extract it back

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape

I am using Grape and  storing data in postgres hstore data field. But the problem is that it stores the Hashie::Mash as string and not as object.

```
   data_hash = {'top_key' => {'key1' => 'val1'}}
   db_obj = Model.find(1)
   db_obj.update_attributes(data: data_hash)
```

but after update if you fetch that object data field then it shows

```
   {"top_key"=>"#<Hashie::Mash key1=\"val1\">"}
```

Comment: Could you describe your Model class? are you using postgres with activerecord or another method?

Answer (score 0):

Its due to the nested hash which hstore is unable to handle properly. After using nested-hstore gem problem got fixed.